# How should i move div after decreasing width?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, codepen

My problem is that i that i want to move the red div out from the black overlay after decreasing width, so for example: when the width is 500px, the red div should appear in the green box (body).

I've tried to use display: none; and display: inline, but then i realized that it just work if you want the div in the same place. But i want to change position, so that the red div goes from one position to another. Hope someone can help!

Thanks!

```js
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "100%";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "0%";
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  background: green;
}

.overlay {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.overlay-content {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  background: red;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 20px;
}

.overlay a {
  padding: 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.overlay .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 45px;
  font-size: 60px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .overlay a {
    font-size: 20px
  }
  .overlay .closebtn {
    font-size: 40px;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="myNav" class="overlay">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <div class="overlay-content"></div>
</div>

<span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</span>
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XVyoKp

Comment: When i typed green, i mean the white page (when you close the overlay)

Comment: I am unsure of what exactly is supposed to happen but you could always have a red div in the body and simply show that one and hide the other one when the width is at desired width

Comment: you can edit your question

Comment: But i'm using javascript for a game and i just need one div, i can't have two

Comment: Try fixed positioning. I posted an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Use fixed positioning in your closeNav & openNav It makes the position fixed to a spot in the browser window.

```
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "100%";
  var overlay = window.document.getElementsByClassName("overlay-content")[0];
  overlay.style.left = "-1000px";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "0%";
  var overlay = window.document.getElementsByClassName("overlay-content")[0];
  overlay.style.position = "fixed";
  overlay.left = "40px;"
}
```